# Can one do deeparadhana and pooja after 12pm? If not, why?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, temple, puja, vedic-rituals

Is daily worship and deeparadhan after 12pm okay? Please give appropriate reasoning

Comment: Did you see my answer below or you missed it?

Answer (score 7):

[Purvanha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/purvanha) or forenoon is the best time for doing rites related to Devas (deities). Where as afternoon ([Aparanha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/aparanha)) is best suited for performing rites related to deceased ancestors.

The following verses from Manu Smriti have the words Purvanha (translated as morning) and Aparanha (translated as afternoon) in them.

> 3.255. **The afternoon**, Kusa grass, the due preparation of the dwelling, sesamum grains, liberality, the careful preparation of the
> food, and (the company of) distinguished Brahmanas **are true riches
> at all funeral sacrifices.**
>
> 3.256. Know that Kusa grass, purificatory (texts), **the morning**, sacrificial viands of all kinds, and those means of purification,
> mentioned above, **are blessings at a sacrifice to the gods**.

That means, afternoon (mid day till sunset) is best suited for funeral rites where as forenoon (sunrise till mid day) is best suited for performing rites for Deities.

So, it is better to complete the daily Puja before mid day.

Now, it should be noted that the above is the view of the Smritis and according to the Smritis only the day is suitable for rites and not the night.

The Agamas/Tantras hold a different view on this. As you can see in temples, Pujas and Archanas are done during night too and that's because rules of temple worship are based on the Tantras and not the Smritis.

Regarding the suitable times of performing the various types of Pujas (Nitya, Naimittika and Kamya), Lord Shiva says:

> nityArchanam dine kuryAt rAtrau naimttikArchanam |
>  ubhayoh
> kAmya-karmAni cheti shAstrasya nirnayah ||
>
> Nitya Karma-s are to be done during the day, Naimittika Karma-s during
> the night; KAmya Karma-s can be performed both in the day or in the night
> --- and this is the conclusion of the scriptures.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram Chapter 11; Verse 8**

Therefore, as per Tantras, anytime in the day is good for performing Nitya Puja (daily obligatory acts of worship).

*[Nitya Puja - Daily obligatory Puja; Naimittika Pujas - Occasional rites; Kamya Pujas - Occasional rites done with the goal of fulfilling specific desires]*

Answer (score 1):

There is not **straight answer** to this but I will answer with respect to **several situations.**

It totally depends on what you mean by pooja and what is meaning of the question. If the question says if we **wake up late** and do pooja late in temple or the sacred place inside our houses then no **its not the right** **practice** one must first worship in **Bramhamuhurata** early morning that the right time to **wake up**.

If you intend to ask that any kind of worship can be done in noon 'also' or not then here is a verse from Devi Bahgvatam which suggests to do Sandhyavanda three times in a day.

> 1-24. Nārāyaṇa said :-- Now I am speaking of the very holy Sandhyopāsanā method of Sandhyā worship of Gāyatrī, the Presiding Deity of the **morning, midday and evening,** and of the twice-born. Listen. The greatness of using Bhasma has been described in detail. No further need be stated on the subject. I shall talk, first of all, of the morning Sandhyā. **The morning Sandhyā is to be done early in the morning while the stars are visible. When the Sun is in the meridian, the midday Sandhyā is to be performed; and while the Sun is visibly going down, the evening Sandhyā is to be recited over.**

Now it also comes to the fact how you are going to do pooja, some people chants names of the lord in that case it you must refer the scriptures and follow them for example **Visnu Sahasranama** is supposed to be chanted in morning after bath.

But the rule is valid only for **for chanting** other than mental chanting for mental chanting there is no rule as such it can be done **anytime anywhere**-

> Anase Tu Niyamo NAstyeva | TathAcha Asuchirbba SuchirvApi Gacchan Stishthan Swapannapi | ... Na Dosha MAnase JApye Sarvadesepi SarvadAhA ||

> There are **no rules for mAnasa japa**. Whether one is pure or impure , whether one is traveling, eating or while lying on bed mental japa can always be done.... There are no sthanAdi doshas in mAnasa japa. (That is there is no need to consider purity of place of japa etc).

Regarding **deeparadhana** I see temples doing it in morning and evening only so in my opinion that is how it is.

To conclude **waking up late is not promoted by Sashtras** first worship should be done in morning only after taking bath.
Apart from that if you want to worship anytime else abide by the rules of scriptures depending on the **kind of worship you do**.